# HTML select a row under the <td> tag in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, html, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` in which I have loaded a htmlString which contains the text in a table format under the  tag. The  tag is inside the  tag. Under the  tag. What I need to do is change the color of the text on tap.

**Code :**

```
<tr id = '1' valign=\"top\">
  <td>
    <p>
      <a href = '#1'> TEXT </a>
    </p>
  </td>
  <td>
    <p>
      <a href = '#1'> TRANSLATION </a>
    </p>
  </td>
</tr>
```

What I need is when tap on "TEXT" OR "TRANSLATION" THE TEXT COLOR SHOULD CHANGE.

I am writing this javascript code to change color.

```
<script> var el = document.getElementById(\"%d\"); 
     window.onload = function () {
     window.scrollTo(20,el.offsetTop); 
     el.style.color=\"red\"; 
   } 
</script>
```

Please help.

**Update:**

This is my html file where i am replacing the above given "tr" tag with ###CONTENT###

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type='text/css'>

        a:link {
            text-decoration : none;
            color: black;
        }

        a:visited {
            color: black;
        }

        a:hover {
            color: red;
        }


        table {
            table-layout: fixed;
            width: 280px;
        }
        html,body {
            margin: 0;padding: 0;
        }
        html {
            display: table;
        }
        body {
            font-family:'MSH-Quraan1';
            font-size:17px;
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            ###CONTENT###
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use javascript?

Trying using CSS like this

```
tr #1:active{
color:red}
```

I am no expert on javascript but try this:

```
<script>

    document.getElementById('1').onclick = changeColor;   

    function changeColor() {
        document.body.style.color = "red";
        return false;
    }   

</script>
```

Comment: I tried this. Active is a property of <a> tag. Doesn't work in <tr> tag.

Comment: I have used CSS too. I have updated my question with the code. Please check.

Comment: That is my problem too. I m also not an expert in js or html or css. But the code you gave, i have tried. This code,i.e., onclick event works on button, and not on <a> tag. But thanks for giving it a try.